# Publish an AWS custom SNS message using AWS RDS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-sns

I want to be able to publish a custom sns message to an SNS topic via an SQL Server stored procedure. E.g. is there an AWS function that does this? Or any other way WITHOUT using a third party library.

```
EXEC xx.sp_sns_publish @topic = 'xxxx', @message = 'my custom message'
```

Any ideas on how this can be done?  Not that I am not after RDS Event Subscriptions, unless there is a way to manipulate that to send a custom message.

I would also like to extend this further by asking if anyone has been able to successfully do an API call from within a stored procedure on AWS RDS.

This is quite easy on a standalone SQL (which I am contemplating moving back to), but on AWS RDS not so easy.

Comment: There are capabilities like this for Aurora and MySQL, but I don't think it is available for SQL Server.

Comment: Have you looked into SQLCLR?

Comment: Sadly AWS dropped support for SQLCLR for Server versions 2017+.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/migrate-your-sql-server-workload-with-clr-integration-to-aws/